# Nexus 7 can't rotate in xfce?

Tags: xfce, nexus-7

I installed xfce4 on my Nexus 7 running Ubuntu and after logging into it, I noticed that the desktop is basically stuck in portrait mode because auto-rotation doesn't work in it (I tried logging in while in landscape mode, and it instantly switched to portrait). When I try to rotate the desktop in the settings, the touch controls are also rotated. Is there a workaround or fix at this present moment, or is this a bug?

Comment: It may not work well as there theoretically isn't an X server running on the Nexus 7 which is what xfce4 is going to be looking for.

Comment: This has been fixed (in recent *saucy* dailies), but is currently (21-Jun) broken. *Work in Progress ..*